# React Native border width issue on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, border

I am new to React Native and also have little to no experience with React JS.

I have an app with screens that are built of ScrollView component containing Views of different heights. If I open the app on iPhone 7, bottom borders of these View components have bigger width the higher the View component is (the more content it contains). These Views have very simple css as below:

```
screenSection: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#333438',
    marginBottom: 48,
},
```

Ive also tried adding / PixeslRatio.get() after borderBottomWidth but it didnt help.

This happens only on physical Iphone devices, not in Iphone Simulator on Mac or even on Android devices.

Anyone have a clue what can be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Code sample:

```
<ScrollView>

    <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#333438', marginBottom: 48,}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginHorizontal: 24}}>Section1 Title</Text>

        <View style={{marginHorizontal: 24}}>
            <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: colors.darkGray, paddingBottom: 10,}}>
                <Text>SubSection Title</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 32, width: '100%'}}>
                <Text>Some content (does not have to be text)</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>

    <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#333438', marginBottom: 48,}} >
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginHorizontal: 24}}>Section2 Title</Text>

        <View style={{marginHorizontal: 24}}>
            <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: colors.darkGray, paddingBottom: 10,}}>
                <Text>SubSection1 Title</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 32, width: '100%'}}>
                <Text>Some content (does not have to be text)</Text>
            </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{marginHorizontal: 24}}>
            <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: colors.darkGray, paddingBottom: 10,}}>
                <Text>SubSection2 Title</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 32, width: '100%'}}>
                <Text>Some content (does not have to be text)</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

The second Section will have thicker borderBottom because it has 2 subsections

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: if your view components contains text, perhaps fontScaling is causing the issue. look under Accessibility > Larger Text on your physical iphone 7 and disable it to see if it helps.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the notice. Code example has been added, i hope its reproducible enough